# Find control in ListView EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview, findcontrol

I have the a `ListView` like this

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
      <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" text="some text"/>
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
   ...
</asp:ListView>
```

In `Page_Load()` I have the following:

```
Literal x = (Literal)ListView1.FindControl("Literal1");
x.Text = "other text";
```

but `x` returns `null`. I’d like to change the text of the `Literal` control but I don’t have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe that unless you call the `DataBind` method of your `ListView` somewhere in code behind, the `ListView` will never try to data bind. Then nothing will render and even the `Literal` control won’t be created.

In your `Page_Load` event try something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //ListView1.DataSource = ...
        ListView1.DataBind();

        //if you know its empty empty data template is the first parent control
        // aka Controls[0]
        Control c = ListView1.Controls[0].FindControl("Literal1");
        if (c != null)
        {
            //this will atleast tell you  if the control exists or not
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in the databound method? I'd rather *not* hardcode "controls[0]" as that's sloppy.

Comment: if I take out `.Controls[0]` I get an error. Can you help me understand why you need it? It seems like we're telling it the index of the control and the name, I fail to see why both would be necessary.

Comment: @Nick .Controls[0] is a reference to the EmptyDataTemplate object. After you have a reference to that object, you are looking for a control called "Literal1" in the child controls of EmptyDataTemplate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
 protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.EmptyItem)
            {
                 Control c = e.Item.FindControl("Literal1");
                if (c != null)
                {
                    //this will atleast tell you  if the control exists or not
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This'll spot the EmptyItemTemplate. There's also an EmptyDataTemplate which this will not see.

Answer (score 3):

It's not specifically what you asked, but another way to do that kind of thing is like this:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
  <%= Foobar() %>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

where Foobar is defined in your page's code behind file

```
public partial class MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
...
    public string Foobar()
    {
         return "whatever";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach...

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
      <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" text="some text" OnInit="Literal1_Init" />
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
   ...
</asp:ListView>
```

In code-behind...

```
protected void Literal1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Literal).Text = "Some other text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound
    Dim searchValue As String = Replace(Request.QueryString("s"), "", "'")
    Dim searchLiteral2 As Literal = CType(ListView1.FindControl("Literal2"), Literal)
    searchLiteral2.Text = "''" & searchValue & "''"
End Sub
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Answering Broam's question "Is there any way to do this in the databound method? I'd rather not hardcode "controls[0]" as that's sloppy"

```
protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView mylist = ((ListView)sender);
    ListViewItem lvi = null;
    if (mylist.Controls.Count == 1)
        lvi = mylist.Controls[0] as ListViewItem;

    if (lvi == null || lvi.ItemType != ListViewItemType.EmptyItem)
        return;

    Literal literal1 = (Literal)lvi.FindControl("Literal1");
    if (literal1 != null)
        literal1.Text = "No items to display";
}
```

Unfortunately, I've not found a way to not use Controls[0].

In the usual Item events (ItemDataBound or ItemCreate), you can use e.Item of the ListViewItemEventArgs to get the ListViewItem. In the DataBound event, there's only a generic EventArgs.

And on top of that, it seems that ((Control)sender).FindControl("Literal1") doesn't work either (find control from the listview at the top of the tree), hence the use of Controls[0] .FindControl(...) (find control from the listviewitem).