# Find a server side control inside a empty template of a grid view without row data bound event

Tags: asp.net

I have a Grid view in which a text box is present in footer and edit template from where user can update data. i  made a table inside a empty template of a grid and add a server side text box on it so that user can insert data in a grid if there is no record present inside a grid.
There is a server side button present out side the grid, on clicking of that button i m saving  the data that user insert or update via grid. Now i am facing the problem to find out the control present inside the empty template of the grid while i m saving the data.

My code looks like as :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grwBrandInfo" runat="server" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridheaderstyle"
                                    GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="True" BackColor="White"
                                    OnRowCommand="grwBrandInfo_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="grwBrandInfo_RowEditing"
                                    OnRowDeleting="grwBrandInfo_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="grwBrandInfo_RowUpdating"
                                    OnRowDataBound="grwBrandInfo_RowDataBound" OnRowCancelingEdit="grwBrandInfo_RowCancelingEdit"
                                    BorderStyle="None">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quarts">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%#Eval("QUARTS")%>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPERMIT_QUANTITY_ID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("PERMIT_QUANTITY_ID") %>' />
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnQuarts" runat="server" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPERMIT_QUANTITY_ID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("PERMIT_QUANTITY_ID") %>' />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFootQuarts" runat="server" CssClass="txtfields" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPERMIT_QUANTITY_ID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("PERMIT_QUANTITY_ID") %>' />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditQuarts" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%#Eval("QUARTS")%>'
                                                    CssClass="txtfields" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" CssClass="hypfield"
                                                    CommandName="Insert" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Action" ShowDeleteButton="true"
                                            ValidationGroup="save">
                                            <ItemStyle CssClass="hypfield" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                            <ControlStyle CssClass="hypfield" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </asp:CommandField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr align="Left" bgcolor="#726E6D">
                                                <td>
                                                    <b>
                                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPERMIT_QUANTITY_ID" runat="server" Value='0' />
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuarts" runat="server" ForeColor="white" Text="Quarts" CssClass="lblfields"></asp:Label></b>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr align="left" id="trEntryNotCompleted" runat="server" bgcolor="#FFFFEE">
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuarts" runat="server" CssClass="txtfields5char" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </td>
                                                                                           </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" CssClass="gridheaderstyle" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                </asp:GridView> 

   <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

So the problem is that how did i find the value of txtQuarts present in the empty template when i am saving data

Comment: You can find control in a similar way as describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613277/find-control-in-listview-emptydatatemplate)

Comment: well i already tried this. But it not working :(

Answer (score -1):

> Dim txtId As String = CType(gridHelpDesk.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtId"), TextBox).Text